# Power Tool - Internal Server Error issue in Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, iis-and-asp.net, powertools

There is a Power tool for "ViewLocalizedItems" which is set up in Tridion 2011 Sp1,
I am trying to move it to Tridion 2013 Sp1.

The power tool is configured and page is coming with the proper text fields, but it is not working after clicking "submit" / "OK".

Gives - 500 Internal Server Error.

While hunting for more details, I found some of the Assembly missing and since i am using .Net 4.5, the older application that i am moving is MVC 3.0, can be an issue.

As Robert is guessing, It may be version issue for MVC and the WebServiceStack version because of which this is occurring.

Attaching the Screen Shot !

Is there any Power tool for 2013 cms to "View Localized Items" for a component and/or its field?

Comment: Sorry :-( Image attachment fails for me.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking. Do you want help troubleshooting the issue you are getting? There isn't an existing PowerTool for this.

Comment: Ahh ! No worries, I fixed it.. There was some issues with Bindings.
But thanks anyways, i guess i could not post the question in right way. But will take care next time. :)